# Month sequence number in a quarter

Tags: database, oracle

I want to determine Month sequence number in its quarter by sql

I found this code but for week:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-"Q"Q-"W"' )
     || ( 7 + TRUNC( SYSDATE + 1, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Q' ) + 1, 'IW' ) ) / 7
         AS "Current Time"
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. For example, posting some sample data and desired result could be useful to clarify your need

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a numeric value from 1-3 representing the month-within-the-quarter value:

```
select case mod(to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'MM')), 3)
         when 0 then 3
         when 1 then 1
         when 2 then 2
       end as month_in_quarter
  from dual;
```

It uses the modulus (mod) function to get a value from 0 - 2. Then converts 0 to 3 since you want March, June, September, and December to be 3, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Numerically the first month in Q1 is 1; the first in Q2 is 4; etc. So the month within the current quarter is `mod(<month> - 1, 3) + 1`, adjusting so you don't end up with month zero (as pointed out by @GriffeyDog). So you can do:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-"Q"Q-"M"')
  || (MOD(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) - 1, 3) + 1) AS "Current Time" 
FROM DUAL;

Current Time                                     
-------------------------------------------------
2017-Q2-M1
```

Checking with a range of dates:

```
with t as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), level - 6) as dt
  from dual
  connect by level < 20
)
select dt, to_char(dt, 'YYYY-"Q"Q-"M"')
  || (mod(extract(month from dt) - 1, 3) + 1) as "Current Time" 
from t;

DT         Current Time                                     
---------- -------------------------------------------------
2016-11-01 2016-Q4-M2                                       
2016-12-01 2016-Q4-M3                                       
2017-01-01 2017-Q1-M1                                       
2017-02-01 2017-Q1-M2                                       
2017-03-01 2017-Q1-M3                                       
2017-04-01 2017-Q2-M1                                       
2017-05-01 2017-Q2-M2                                       
2017-06-01 2017-Q2-M3                                       
2017-07-01 2017-Q3-M1                                       
2017-08-01 2017-Q3-M2                                       
2017-09-01 2017-Q3-M3                                       
2017-10-01 2017-Q4-M1                                       
2017-11-01 2017-Q4-M2                                       
2017-12-01 2017-Q4-M3                                       
2018-01-01 2018-Q1-M1                                       
2018-02-01 2018-Q1-M2                                       
2018-03-01 2018-Q1-M3                                       
2018-04-01 2018-Q2-M1                                       
2018-05-01 2018-Q2-M2
```

Comment: That will make June be month 0 instead of month 3.

Comment: Oops, of course it will; modified to adjust back and forth.